# How can C++ compilers support C++11 atomic, but not support C++11 memory model

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, memory-model

While looking at Clang and g++ C++11 implementation status I noticed something strange:
they support C++11 atomics, but they dont support C++11 memory model.
I was under impression that you must have C++11 memory model to use atomics. 
So what exactly is the difference between support for atomics and memory model?
Does a lack of memory model support means that legal C++11 programs that use `std::atomic<T>` arent seq consistent?

references:
http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html

Comment: Atomicity is one of (three?) properties of memory model, along with memory visibility and memory ordering. Atomicity is not a 'synonym' of memory model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the issues is the definition of "memory location", that allows (and forces the compiler to support) locking different structure members by different locks. There is a [discussion about a RL problem caused by this](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-02/msg00005.html).

Basically the issue is that having a `struct` defined like this:

```
struct x {
    long a;
    unsigned int b1;
    unsigned int b2:1;
};
```

the compiler is free to implement writing to `b2` by overwriting `b1` too (and apparently, judging from the report, it does). Therefore, the two fields have to be locked as one. However, as a consequence of the C++11 memory model, this is forbidden (well, not really forbidden, but the compiler must ensure simultaneous updates to `b1` and `b2` do not interfere; it could do it by locking or CAS-ing each such update, well, life is difficult on some architectures). Quoting from the report:

> I've raised the issue with our GCC guys and they said to me that: "C does
>   not provide such guarantee, nor can you reliably lock different
>   structure fields with different locks if they share naturally aligned
>   word-size memory regions.  The C++11 memory model would guarantee this,
>   but that's not implemented nor do you build the kernel with a C++11
>   compiler."

Nice info can also be found in the [wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM).

Comment: to technical for me, but this is nice info: The reason we mention C11/C++11 memory model is because we plan to support
that, likely for GCC 4.8, when requested by some options (either by default
when choosing those standards?, or when explicitly requested).  This will
even disable some optimizations that are fine for single-threaded apps,
but aren't fine in those memory models, aren't fine in OpenMP or for many
other threaded programs.  E.g. loop store motion if it isn't guaranteed the
variable is always stored in the loop:

Comment: int x;

void
foo (int j)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    if (i > j)
      x = i;
}
can't be performed, because otherwise it introduces a tmp = x; ... x = tmp;
into code that wouldn't otherwise touch the variable, so if some ... other
thread modifies x, it might have unexpected value.

 Jakub

Comment: cool edit (link is awesome, often I wonder where do ppl that make magic things(compilers)) live and why are they so shy about sharing info. :) fact is that most of the time info is there, but not easily googlable :)

Comment: Is this answer still accurate? I'd be surprised if GCC still doesn't support this...

Answer (score 12):

I guess the "Lack of memory model" in these cases just means that the optimizers were written before the C++11 memory model got published, and might perform now invalid optimizations. It's very difficult and time-consuming to validate optimizations against the memory model, so it's no big surprise that the clang/gcc teams haven't finished that yet.

> Does a lack of memory model support means that legal C++11 programs that use std::atomic arent seq consistent?

Yes, that's a possibility. It's even worse: the compiler might introduce data races into (according to the C++11 standard) race-free programs, e.g. by introducing speculative writes.

For example, several C++ compilers used to perform this optimization:

```
for (p = q; p = p -> next; ++p) {
    if (p -> data > 0) ++count;
}
```

Could get optimized into:

```
register int r1 = count;
for (p = q; p = p -> next; ++p) {
    if (p -> data > 0) ++r1;
}
count = r1;
```

If all `p->data` are non-negative, the original source code did not write to `count`, but the optimized code does. This can introduce a data race in an otherwise race-free program, so the C++11 specification disallows such optimizations. Existing compilers now have to verify (and adjust if necessary) all optimizations.

See [Concurrency memory model compiler consequences](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2338.html) for details.

Comment: u know what is funny?  MS says for VC++ 11:  Memory model: N2429 made the Core Language recognize the existence of multithreading, but there appears to be nothing for a compiler implementation to do (at least, one that already supported multithreading).  So it's N/A in the table.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: That's only a very specific part of the entire memory model. The same table also has "Data-dependency ordering" (N2664) which did require work. Ordinarily, we'd count that as part of the C++11 memory model, too.

Comment: Ok .. so they're lazy.  That's what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that they don't support the memory model, but that they don't (yet) support the API in the Standard for interacting with the memory model.  That API includes a number of mutexes.

However, both Clang and GCC have been as thread aware as possible without a formal standard for some time.  You don't have to worry about optimizations moving things to the wrong side of atomic operations.

Comment: That answer is really unsatisfactory; the list of features linked in the question *specifically* talks about the memory model (and its proposal), not any API, library, mutexes and whatnot. Moreover, at least gcc 4.7 *does* have the mutexes in the library. Talk like "as thread aware as possible without a formal standard" is just bullshit; it doesn't mean anything. Thread aware tells you nothing about what the compiler does and there's certainly more to it than "moving things to the wrong side of atomic operations".

Comment: @jpalecek while I agree that answer isnt that great there is no need to say bs.  :) And yeah mutexes are in g++ from 4.6 at least, though if I remember correctly atomic_thread_fence wasnt. :) Cant check now, (Im on the VS atm).

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: atomic_thread_fence is in gcc-4.7. I used the term BS to refer to vague marketing phrases, like "native support for ...", that seem to be important, but after a little bit of thinking, they don't mean anything.

Comment: Both the Clang and GCC links point to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2429.htm , which includes memory model rules (e.g., "what's a race?") **and** what could be considered an API for working iwth that model (e.g., "The library defines a number of atomic operations (clause 29[atomics]) and operations on locks (clause 30[thread]) that are specially identified as synchronization operations. These operations play a special role in making assignments in one thread visible to another.").